# How to change the s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0' in Flutter.podspec file?

Tags: xcode, flutter

Hello I would try to change this value to see if it resolve my issue. But when I modify this value and run app, after build error the value come back to 8.0

Flutter.podspec

```
  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Flutter.podspec` is only used as a local source, to change the target, open the module in `Xcode`, if you are in `Android Studio` you can do it clicking the next link:

[image: Open iOS module in Xcode]

and then change the `Target` in the `Deployment Info section` from the `General Tab` in the `Runner`.

[image: Runner]

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have 9.0 in Deployment info but have  s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0' it's normal ?

Comment: Flutter supports iOS 8.0 and later. If your app includes Objective-C or Swift code that makes use of APIs that were unavailable in iOS 8, you can update it appropriately, for more info please check: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios